# Invert a AC signal without inverting the DC offset with it?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, dc, inverter

I'm trying to find a differential amplifier that allows us to invert only AC signals and ignores inverting DC offset. The goal is to make sure that the DC offset stays positive (and does not end up being negative) after the signal has been inverted. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you must separate, modify, then sum.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Since it's a differential amplifier, will you need to preserve the polarity of both the differential DC and common-mode DC, or just the common-mode?

Answer (score 1):

An all-pass filter can do this if you can get the phase transition region to occur at the frequencies you don't care about.

[image]

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-Bode-plot-of-an-all-pass-filter-b-an-all-pass-filter-schematic_fig2_329392804